# In ListLinePlot3D, plotting a complicated curvy line, can I add arrows at regular intervals?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'm plotting a curvy line with LitLinePlot3D, and it's difficult to visually trace the line. I would like to add arrows at regular intervals along the line to better understand the plot. How could this be done?

Comment: Please post your Mathematica code.

Comment: Can you adapt this `curvy=Table[{t,Sin[t]},{t,0,2Pi,Pi/8}]; arrows=Table[Arrow[{curvy[[4t]],curvy[[4t+1]]}],{t,1,4}]; Show[Graphics[arrows], ListLinePlot[curvy]]` You take adjacent points from your curvy line using Table, make those pairs into Arrows and then use Show to display those Arrows on top of the curve your are plotting now. If 4t gives you too many arrows then make it 6t or 8t or 20t.

Comment: Bill: Thank you. This will work well for my purposes. Peter